# how to convert ant design class component to function component

Tags: reactjs, antd

Can anyone please suggest me how to convert ant design class component into the function-based component. My application is almost a function based component. I am much familiar with function-based component but class-based component I am not familiar with. Can anyone please suggest some idea to convert class-based component to function based component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Steps, Button, message } from 'antd';

const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'First-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Second-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Last',
    content: 'Last-content',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
    };
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Steps current={current}>
          {steps.map(item => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">
          {current < steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => message.success('Processing complete!')}>
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button style={{ margin: '0 8px' }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I am new to react not much familiar with class component. I understand function based component easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's pretty straighforward as you only have one variable in the local state.
You could just remove the functions and update directly the state from the setCurrent variable from useState in the onClick events.

This would be the simplest soultion I could think of

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Steps, Button, message } from "antd";

const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
  {
    title: "First",
    content: "First-content"
  },
  {
    title: "Second",
    content: "Second-content"
  },
  {
    title: "Last",
    content: "Last-content"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Steps current={current}>
        {steps.map(item => (
          <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
        ))}
      </Steps>
      <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
      <div className="steps-action">
        {current < steps.length - 1 && (
          <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setCurrent(curr => curr + 1)}>
            Next
          </Button>
        )}
        {current === steps.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
          >
            Done
          </Button>
        )}
        {current > 0 && (
          <Button style={{ margin: "0 8px" }} onClick={() => setCurrent(curr => curr - 1)}>
            Previous
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```